# Asp.net 4.5 bundling Script.Render throws exception

Tags: asp.net, bundle

After adding bundling to the project and going through a Microsoft tutorial on MSDN, 
I am started to get the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

On following line of code:

```
<%:System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/bundles/Styles") %>
```

I've tried to look for this reference, but in my solution there is no reference to this DLL. Anyone faced with something similar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this missing dependency would be to simply grab it using the NuGet package manager, e.g.

```
install-package WebGrease
```

...or right clicking on your package, managing NuGet packages, and searching for it.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade bootstrap to version 4.5.3 solved the problem for me...